# Missing required parameters for [Route: unpublish_category] [URI: category/unpublished/{id}]

Tags: php, laravel

This is the **web.php**:

```
Route::get('/category/unpublished/{id}',[
    'uses'=>'CategoryController@unpublish_category',
    'as'=>'unpublish_category'
]);
```

This is the **CategoryController**:

```
public function unpublish_category($id){
        return $id;
}
```

and this is the **View**:

```
<a href="{{route('unpublish_category',['cat_id'=>$category->id])}}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Unpublish</a>
```

Whenever I do the above, I get an error like:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: unpublish_category] [URI: category/unpublished/{id}]. (View: C:\Users\rhy_a\OneDrive\Desktop\eCommerce\resources\views\admin\category\category_manage.blade.php)
```

Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: your route parameter is named `id` so why are you passing the key `cat_id` when generating the route?

Comment: Change your code to `{{ route('unpublish_category',['id'=>$category->id]) }}` or `{{ route('unpublish_category', $category->id) }}`

Comment: How silly I was. thanks anyway sir. @sta

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to  :

```
{{ route('unpublish_category', ['id'=>$category->id]) }}
```

Or,

```
{{ route('unpublish_category', $category->id) }}
```